# Finding reason for visa refusal when original refusal letter is lost

Tags: usa, uk, visa-refusals, visa-rejections

How do you get to know about the previous visa refusal reason if you have lost the refusal letter? My friend's parents applied for a US visa in 2007 and the application was refused. They don't have the refusal letter now and they don't seem to remember why the application was rejected. They want to apply for the visa to the UK now. Is there a way to find out the reason for rejection as they need to fill this information in the new visa application.

Comment: The US is not very forthcoming with information about rejection reasons, but there should indeed have been a letter citing a specific paragraph of the immigration law.  I do not know whether it is possible to get that information now.

Comment: Wouldn't they know the reason? Surely no country would rely on people reapplying after a visa refusal to state the correct refusal reason?

Comment: It is very strange to incredulous not to remember why one was refused a visa. In any case USA gives a generic reason usually one of two. Basically they are not convinced the parents will return.

Comment: How incredulous as it may seem to you but it wouldn't change the fact. If they knew it then I wouldn't be asking this question here. If you want I can explain further how it could happen but I think that would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Let them apply.
In the form there will be a question about previous visa applications. They should answer they have applied for an US visa and did not get it, if by then they remember details they can add them, otherwise they should mention not remembering and not having the letter anymore. It would be a very common thing as people do lose letters for many reasons.

Their application should be the best they can get it, including all information the UK visa people ask for but non they do not want.
If their circumstances have changed from when they last applied, the reason for denial would not be important.
And also it is for a different country which has different (if alike) rules and reasons to allow or deny people visa.